# Combine a trailing-stop with a stop-limit or similar?

Tags: signals, pine-script

I'm trying to to the following: I wish to use **trail_offset** in **my strategy.exit()**, but also don't want the price to go lower that the initial entry price.
Let's say I have 2% trailing stop. If I use:

```
ts = input(2, title="TrailingStop%", type=input.float)
ts_calc = close * (1/tick) * ts * 0.01
strategy.exit("ExitLong", "RSILong", trail_points=0, trail_offset=ts_calc)
```

the price can also drop 2% off my entry direction (in this case, being long, 2% below) and I don't want this. I want the strategy to exit it at least where I started or, let's say, 0.5% below.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Trying this (example for long positions), not sure if it'll work:

```
stop_limit= close

if ConditionEntryL
    strategy.entry('RSILong', strategy.long)
    stop_limit := close

if close >= stop_limit
    strategy.exit('ExitLong', 'RSILong', trail_points=0, trail_offset=ts_calc)
else
    strategy.close('RSILong')
```

Shall it close position as soon as it goes below entry price?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. It looks like that "if close >= stop_limit" condition is not being updated constantly, in order to determine what to do. It should be checked at every tick. Pls help.